# Cannot ssh into Raspberry Pi after halt

Tags: ssh

So i was doing my things when my dad connected to the wrong Pi and halted it now when we boot it up

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.141 port 22: Connection timed out`

Even after checking the router the router says that it´s offline even tho it´s not

Does anyone have a fix?
(Raspberry Pi 4B 2GB RAM)

Comment: perhaps it got a different IP address ... have you tried `ssh pi@raspberry.local` (assuming you did not change the pi's host name) - how do you know it's not offline? can you `ping` it? do you have a keyboard and display attached?

Comment: When i pinged it it said Destination host unreachable and i cannot know if it did change its ip adress cuz it isnt showing up in the router even though the port led is blinking also raspberry.local says No such hostname is known

Comment: With the information given, my best guess is to flash a new SD card & start over. If you have data you need to recover, you can mount the current SD card once you've successfully booted with the new sd card & copy as needed.

Comment: This seems like a genuine request for help, but you haven't supplied any details of what OS, how it is connected etc. so you are unlikely to get any meaningful answers. Either restore from your backup or do a fresh install.

Comment: connect keyboard and screen - problem solved

Comment: sounds like a network related issue if you know for a fact that the pi is not offline but appears to be.  sometimes one connects via wireless but looks at wired config...

Comment: What were the "things" you were doing?  How did your dad "connect to the wrong computer"?  Are you running the pi headless?  Please edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

If the details in your question are complete and accurate, you can restore your RPi by simply removing power (pull the USB power connector), and re-applying it.

The `halt` command stops processing, but **it does not** remove power.